# How to add plus minus to follow by ui slider handler with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

How to add plus and minus like on attached img to jquery ui slider to follow by handler.
Plus and minus on click must change values on slider?

[image: How to add plus like on picture attached to jquery ui slider?]

Answer (score 0):

I won't just code for you, but give you guidance.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9qwmX/2/) to learn how to make a movable container(tooltip) above the slider handle. Add two buttons(+ and -) to the tooltip and style them or give suitable images. When + and - buttons are clicked, change the value of slider accordingly:

```
//When + button is clicked
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );

$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", value + 10 );
```